# how to get key values and key value pairs of array

Tags: php

Here I am trying to parse two dimensional array using `php`

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 10
            [3] => 13
            [4] => 15
            [5] => 17
            [6] => 21
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [1] => 9
            [2] => 23
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 23
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [1] => 12
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 11
            [3] => 21
            [4] => 23
        )

)
```

this array come from a scheduler : `https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/appointment-week-view-scheduler.html`

Here key value `1,2,3,4,5,..` are days of week..,`1` stands for `Monday` and `0-23` stands for `hrs` of the day.

Here I want to store day of the week and `Hrs` of the day in a variable for MySQL,using loops.

Comment: What is your expected output? As well as what you have tried so far? Add both in your question.

Comment: foreach($array as $key=>$value)
{
  echo $key;

}

Comment: your question is too broad, to start off you'd need to learn which api to use, mysqli or PDO

Comment: my question is to store key of array in variable and key value pair in another variable using loops.., i am using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use 2 for(;;) loops

```
for($outerLoop=0; $outerLoop<count($arrMain); $outerLoop++ ) {
    $innerArray = $arrMain[$outerLoop];
    for($innerLoop=0; $innerLoop<count($innerArray); $innerLoop++ ) {
       //--- do your stuff with the data
    } // end innerLoop
} // end outerLoop
```